# Start Time in TestNG default Report

Tags: testng

I have used TestNG for my Project.

The default report generated after the execution shows: `Start Time as 1486475432046`.

How can I interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

The start time in TestNG's default report is displayed in **unixtimestamp**. It is defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds. Refer to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to know more about unix time stamp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Have I answered your question satisfactorily?

Comment: Yeah, You answered it